# Why am I losing my object after it is returned?

Tags: vb.net, object

I am working on an app where I am working on my own login.  I create a user and then call the function which returns me a user.  When I do this I can step through the code, I can see I am retirning the user object but when I get back the function it is empty.  Any ideas?  Code calling the function and the function listed below.  Thanks

```
Public Function LoginUser(ByVal displayname As String, ByVal pw As String) As User
    Dim con As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim dtr As SqlDataReader
    Dim strSQL As String = String.Empty
    Dim loggedinUser As New User()
    con = New SqlConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("wlsConnectionString").ConnectionString

    strSQL = "Select * from Users where displayname = @displayname and pw = @pw"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Displayname", displayname)

    con.Open()
    'con.Open()
    dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dtr.Read() Then
        loggedinUser.UserID = 1
        loggedinUser.active = dtr("active")
        loggedinUser.Role = dtr("role_id")
        loggedinUser.Displayname = dtr("displayname")
        loggedinUser.created = dtr("created")
    Else

    End If

    Return loggedinUser
End Function


AttemptedUser.Displayname = UserName.Text
AttemptedUser.pw = Password.Text

AttemptedUser.LoginUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

If AttemptedUser.UserID <> Nothing Then
    Session("userid") = AttemptedUser.UserID
    Session("role") = AttemptedUser.Role
    Session("Displayname") = AttemptedUser.Displayname
End If
```

Comment: What language are you using? That'll go a long way in helping people pay attention to/answer the question.

Comment: My bad. I just assumed. It is vb.net.

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text. Also, please don't build your own authentication systems. It's best to rely on the authentication tools provided by your platform of choice.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the return value:

```
AttemptedUser.LoginUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
```

You run the method, but ignore the `User` object it returns.  You need to put that object in a variable:

```
Dim someUser As User = AttemptedUser.LoginUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
```

Your object/method structure seems a bit disjointed as well.  Note that you set values on an object:

```
AttemptedUser.Displayname = UserName.Text
AttemptedUser.pw = Password.Text
```

Then you pass those same values to that same object which already has them:

```
AttemptedUser.LoginUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
```

And return an entirely different object:

```
Dim loggedinUser As New User()
'...
Return loggedinUser
```

There are a number of different ways to approach this, but I imagine creating a `LoginUser` method as a `Shared` factory method on the `User` object would make more sense.

---

Side note: I can't help but notice that you're storing user passwords in plain text.  Please *never* do that.  User passwords should be hashed and should never be readable.  For a lot more reading on the subject, take a look [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: I will look the code later but I assumed I was doing that.  I agree with the password piece. My plan once I get going is to encrypt the passwords. I was just walking before I crawled.

Comment: @user3849334: You assumed you were assigning the return value?  I don't see how, since that line of code very clearly wasn't assigning it to anything.  I'm not even sure where you were *looking* for the return value after leaving the method in the debugger, since nothing holds that value.  Also, note that there is a very important difference between "encrypt" and "hash."  The former is decrypt-able, the latter is not, and that's critical.